# At what point should editing a question become creating a new question?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

I [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26125494/valgrind-on-mips-reports-no-heap-usage) that is a bit niche. It's about a particular piece of software, ported to an uncommon processor architecture. When I initially asked the question, I shared all the information I had. Over time, I collected more information (on my own and based on comments and answers). I updated the question through editing as I did so. The question and available information has changed significantly.

Ultimately, two and a half weeks later, I unfortunately still don't have a solution (through no fault of the answerers, who have provided nothing but helpful information). I have gone through the recommended steps here on SE (provide thorough information, edit to address questions in the comments, and then try offering a bounty -- I ended up offering two bounties totalling 600 rep). I think I should start over, eliminate my preconceptions, and boil it down to the simplest possible scenario, and ask the same question based on that scenario.

If I do that, should I post it as an update to my current question, or post a new question? At what point does it change enough that it would invalidate the answers already provided (which, while not a solution to my problem, are still excellent sources of information)? Have I already passed that point anyway (check my edit history, it has changed pretty significantly)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> At what point should editing a question become creating a new question?

when the question changes to a different question, although this can be *sometimes* a grey area, certainly with something as so specific as your scenario.

Otherwise, it's still the same question, even if you edit it multiple times to either improve it, provide more info, corrections, etc.

> Over time, I collected more information (on my own and based on comments and answers)

This is improving it. Additional info *relating to the same question* doesn't change the question, it just provides additional data for the question.

> two and a half weeks later, I unfortunately still don't have an answer

There is an answer with 8 upvotes and no downvotes, while doesn't necessarily mean you should therefore have the info/answer you need, it must be a *decent* answer based on community opinion.

I'd say if those answers you already have don't precisely answer what you require, then perhaps your question is not clear enough.

If you were to post an entirely new question, you'd have to be careful not to make a dupe, 
as you'd be essentially asking the same question but worded differently and from a different angle.

However, alternately, editing the current question to ask it in a whole new direction would mean that the current answers (with good upvotes and bounty awards) would likely become inaccurate/bad answers based on the newly structured question, and could attract future downvotes as a result.
Which isn't ideal.

**Potential Resolve**
I see the lesser of two evils here is make an entirely new question.
This leaves the current one as *done* with some answers, one with 8 upvotes, bounty awards etc.

Just make sure the new question is not a dupe, and you are very clear in what you are asking.
I'm sure you have been meticulously reading through your edits and question before posting, but on this occasion, before posting the new one, read it through and ask yourself:
"Could the answers from my previous question suit/answer my new question?"

If yes, then you haven't really asked anything new, which doesn't help the site, or you really.

**Otherwise**, perhaps a good dev/tech forum would be more useful here, where you can have two-and-fro data and comms to get to the bottom of the issue and your needs.

Sometimes a question is more than one question, or is tricky to answer because it requires discussions to get to the root cause and question being asked.

Sometimes Stack doesn't always suit the scenario/question one has, and trying to make your scenario fit into a single answerable question doesn't work out so well.

Comment: Thank you, this is a good, thorough answer. I think your last point (posting on a forum rather than SO) may actually be the *best* solution, as I'm really doing more "troubleshooting" than anything else, but I was hoping to benefit from the expertise here (get help anywhere I can, really). I've had an open question on the mailing list for some time now, maybe that will pan out.

Comment: Also, when I said I don't have an "answer", I meant to say I don't have a "solution". There are several great answers, they just weren't the solution. Question updated.

Comment: Yeah I get the problem with the answer/solution difference. "doesn't necessarily mean you should therefore have the info/answer you need". I think perhaps a forum on this occasion would be better. At least it's easy in forum for people to ask for clarifications on things to head towards a better answer. Although, *Stack chat* has options too, never been to them, but I'm sure I read that you can jump on to a certain room and ask about questions. As you already have a solid SO question, it might work

Comment: If you do get an answer from an outside source, and you think it would be helpful for others don't forget to answer your own question with the details as well though.