# Should this edit be a new question?

Tags: discussion, support, edits

Is the [3rd edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30476127/revisions) of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476127/java-get-last-n-elements-from-stream) eligible for a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)?

I've read [these answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274681/at-what-point-should-editing-a-question-become-creating-a-new-question) but I cannot totally say if we are in a gray area or not.

Original question is resolved, but question is about same and is improved...

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: [Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. It should have been a new question. It completely changes the original question and is more conversational than an actual 'edit'.