# Editing question with answer but asking other question instead

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, answers

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36180029/finding-soap-parameters-without-wsdl) yesterday, and I found a workaround for what I needed, using this workaround however, but I need to ask another question.

Before editing, I would like to ask if I am allowed to edit my question with the solution I found, and also ask for help with the other problem I am facing at the moment.

Or should I just answer my question and ask another question?

Comment: If there would be an answer that answers your question, would it still answer the question, if you edit it? If yes, then edit. If no, then ask a new one.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274681/at-what-point-should-editing-a-question-become-creating-a-new-question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [help center on self-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

> Can I answer my own question?
>
> Yes! Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer
>   their own questions. If you have a question that you already know the
>   answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so
>   that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly
>   okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site

So, answer your own question and ask a new question referencing the first one if necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling this would be what I had to do, but I wasn't sure.